# Was ox more valuable than sheep?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 22:1
"Whoever steals an ox or a sheep and slaughters it or sells it must pay back five head of cattle for the ox and four sheep for the sheep.

Why this difference? Was ox more valuable than sheep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently so - even today oxen are far more expensive to purchase than sheep

One observation from various texts is that people often sacrificed far more sheep than oxen, which suggests to me that they were, in fact, valued more highly. (Someone feel free to correct me if I'm wrong on that point).

For example, from an inventory of sacrifices in Number 7, we read in verse 41 that Shelumiel offered the following:

> ... and for the sacrifice of peace offerings, two oxen, five rams, five male goats, and five male lambs a year old.

Similarly, from 2 Chronicles 7:5:

> King Solomon offered as a sacrifice 22,000 oxen and 120,000 sheep.

In 2 Chronicles 15:11:

> They sacrificed to the Lord on that day from the spoil that they had brought 700 oxen and 7,000 sheep.

Even in an inventory of Solomon's wealth in 1 Kings 4:23, it reported that Solomon's household consumed 100 sheep per day, but only 10 oxen per day.

Feel free to disagree with my argument in this instance, but this strongly suggests that oxen were, in fact, regarded as more valuable (or, at least, more scarce).

The primary uses of oxen recorded in the Bible were for consumption as food, sacrifices, pulling carts, and plowing fields. (Incidentally, 1 Kings 19:19 recorded that Elisha was using 12 yoke of oxen to plow his field, which gives a sense of how many would be required; it also records 4 oxen being used to pull 2 carts in Numbers 7:65, and 12 oxen being used to pull 6 carts in v. 3).

A much more direct piece of evidence comes to us in Job 1:3, which records Job owning 7,000 sheep but only 500 yoke of oxen. Since a yoke of oxen would've been 2, that means he had 7 times as many sheep as he had oxen. At the end of his life, he's recorded as having 14,000 sheep and 1,000 yoke of oxen (42:13), still with the 7:1 ratio. (In fact, it's exactly double what he owned before, but that's a different topic).